# .htaccess to block specific file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I been searching and couldn't find this answer, usually they all ask how to block viewing the file from outside the domain.

I have a website where I don't have access to the  remove a script by hand or Javascript since it executes before I can do it, but I do have access to the folder, so I was thinking if I can add an .htaccess blocking that specific JavaScript file (not all the .js files, only one which is prototype).

Is there any code to do to that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is! Put this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
<Files "example.js">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @thickguru, quick questions before trying it, my script is the following one in the <header>:

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/en-us/js/7115a45cff39943777b62465dfc83c10/prototype/prototype.js"></script>

So I should add it this way?

<Files "http://www.domain.com/en-us/js/7115a45cff39943777b62465dfc83c10/prototype/prototype.js">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>

Or just as:

<Files "prototype.js">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>

Sorry, I never used .htaccess before.

Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Name it whatever the files name is. So, if the file name is prototype.js, name it that. Just make sure the `.htaccess` file is in the same folder as the javascript file.

Comment: Ah ok, problem is the javascript file comes from another place which I don't have access. The header is on another place unfortunately so I think it's not going to work, right?

Comment: Hmm, you **might** be able to put the full directory e.g. `<files "dir1/dir2/dir3/example.js">`. However, normally it needs to go inside the file that the file is located. No harm in testing it though.

Comment: That's great! What did you end up having to do?

Comment: I asked permission to add the .htaccess in the Javascript files and the granted it :)

Comment: Awesome, glad it is all sorted :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for you invaluable help @thickguru!